# ActiveRecord objects not working in EventMachine callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eventmachine, thin

I ran into the following problem when testing my Rails app.

When making an asynchronous HTTP request with EventMachine I cannot use ActiveRecord objects in the callback for some reason.
Whenever I try to access the object I get the following exception:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:144:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?': You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! (NoMethodError)
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:75:in `define_attribute_methods'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `define_attribute_methods'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:257:in `method_missing'
```

If I remove ActiveRecord objects from the callback, it works ok. Unfortunately I really need them to be accessible, so removing is not an option.

It does not matter if I access the object for reading or writing.

The code I have written looks something like this:

```
http = EM::HttpRequest.new(url).get(:query => query)

http.callback do
  ....
  object.status = 'delivered'
  object.save!
  ....
end
```

As for the environment, I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Ruby 1.8.7-p371
- Rails 2.3.18
- Thin server 1.5.0
- ActiveRecord 2.3.18
- EventMachine 1.0.0

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show how do you get 'object'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all I had to do, was modifying my development configuration file.
Setting config.cache_classes = true fixed the problem.

Comment: This is crazy, I've to maintain some legacy Rails 2.3 project.
Do you know why we have this bug in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since this fix has worked well, I haven't had the need to dig further.

Comment: Yeah, but during development we need to restart server everytime we make changes. Or do you know a better way?

Comment: Yes, you have to restart it after changes with cache_classes set to true. But this has never been an issue for me since restart takes only a few seconds and is not needed very often.